# slovakia traffic data not showing on map over js api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, traffic

Does anyone know why google does not provide traffic info for Slovakia on web maps using javascript api ?
It used to work just fine. Now some other countires around are showing traffic but Slovakia is not.
Also maps on maps.google.sk do show traffic data in Slovakia. So what is a problem with traffic over js api in Slovakia? is there any legal issue google got into so they had to pull it off? or what's up?

Apparently similar situation is with Czech and Poland..

Topic was closed due to non technical question so i had to reedit. Thanks All for comments, although they are All to point and relevant, I want to point out again that traffic used to show over js api v 3 already and it still is showing on maps.google.sk. So Google definitely does have data. 
Now the technical question, how to make it show for slovakia using maps javascript api?

Thnaks.

------ EDIT ------

As of few days ago 25.Feb.2014, traffic info started to show again in Slovakia.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know details about the underlying reasons for status, but here is a list of the Google Maps API coverage status for **Slovakia** (unfortunately, traffic is not included):

- Map Tiles: Yes
- Gecoding: Yes
- Street View: No
- **Traffic: No**
- Driving Directions: Yes (Major Cities)
- Business Listings: No
- Domain: No
- Biking Directions: No

For **Czech Republic**:

- Map Tiles: Yes
- Gecoding: Yes
- Street View: Yes
- **Traffic: No**
- Driving Directions: Yes
- Business Listings: Yes
- Domain: Yes (cz)
- Biking Directions: No

And for **Poland**:

- Map Tiles: Yes
- Gecoding: Yes
- Street View: No
- **Traffic: No**
- Driving Directions: Yes
- Business Listings: Yes
- Domain: Yes (pl)
- Biking Directions: No

The [Google Maps Coverage List](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html) shows the status of these elements for countries around the world.

Comment: Over the last seven years there's been a general consensus that absence of facilities like this is usually down to lack of data (there's no infrastructure to provide it) or licensing issues (the people who have the data want too much money for it, or want to protect their own outlet). Google have hinted as much and never denied it. [It is almost exactly seven years: the first API was launched at the end of June 2005]

Comment: Thats what i thought as well at first but google is showing the traffic info on maps.google.sk. So why not over api if its already public.

Comment: Almost certainly licensing. Google are allowed to present the data on their site, but not allow anyone else access to the data. Or maybe they are trialling it on their site prior to allowing the API to use it. (They never announce additions in advance, although Google Maps usually gets new things first)